# Why these Py4JJavaError showString errors while reading BQ partition Spark dataframes using pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataproc

I am trying to read BQ table by partition, and getting error on function `show` as well as `cache`. The data itself is not large but it started failing, count() gives results `dataframe size 2369180`.

`gcs-connector-version :1.9.16`

`bigquery-connector-version :0.13.16`

`dataproc version: 1.4.9-debian9`

`````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/pyspark-job_dc164478/main.py", line 96, in <module>
    job_module.job(sc, spark_session, args.job_name, **job_args)
  File "jobs.zip/jobs/my_job/job.py", line 91, in analyze
  File "jobs.zip/jobs/my_job/job.py", line 26, in extract_data
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 380, in show
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o85.showString.
: com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.api.gax.rpc.InternalException: com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INTERNAL: request failed: internal error
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.api.gax.rpc.ApiExceptionFactory.createException(ApiExceptionFactory.java:67)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:72)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:60)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcExceptionCallable$ExceptionTransformingFuture.onFailure(GrpcExceptionCallable.java:97)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.api.core.ApiFutures$1.onFailure(ApiFutures.java:68)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$CallbackListener.run(Futures.java:1072)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.DirectExecutor.execute(DirectExecutor.java:30)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.executeListener(AbstractFuture.java:1164)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.complete(AbstractFuture.java:958)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.setException(AbstractFuture.java:749)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$GrpcFuture.setException(ClientCalls.java:522)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$UnaryStreamToFuture.onClose(ClientCalls.java:497)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.closeObserver(ClientCallImpl.java:426)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.access$500(ClientCallImpl.java:66)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.close(ClientCallImpl.java:689)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.access$900(ClientCallImpl.java:577)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInternal(ClientCallImpl.java:751)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:740)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Suppressed: com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.api.gax.rpc.AsyncTaskException: Asynchronous task failed
        at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.api.gax.rpc.ApiExceptions.callAndTranslateApiException(ApiExceptions.java:57)
        at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.api.gax.rpc.UnaryCallable.call(UnaryCallable.java:112)
        at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigquery.storage.v1.BigQueryReadClient.createReadSession(BigQueryReadClient.java:230)
        at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.direct.DirectBigQueryRelation.buildScan(DirectBigQueryRelation.scala:126)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceStrategy$$anonfun$10.apply(DataSourceStrategy.scala:293)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceStrategy$$anonfun$10.apply(DataSourceStrategy.scala:293)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceStrategy$$anonfun$pruneFilterProject$1.apply(DataSourceStrategy.scala:326)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceStrategy$$anonfun$pruneFilterProject$1.apply(DataSourceStrategy.scala:325)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceStrategy.pruneFilterProjectRaw(DataSourceStrategy.scala:403)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceStrategy.pruneFilterProject(DataSourceStrategy.scala:321)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceStrategy.apply(DataSourceStrategy.scala:289)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$1.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:63)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$1.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:63)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:435)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:441)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.plan(QueryPlanner.scala:93)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:78)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:75)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1334)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.foldLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foldLeft(Iterator.scala:1334)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:75)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:67)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:435)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:441)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.plan(QueryPlanner.scala:93)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.sparkPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:72)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.sparkPlan(QueryExecution.scala:68)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:77)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan(QueryExecution.scala:77)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3359)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2544)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2758)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.getRows(Dataset.scala:254)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:291)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INTERNAL: request failed: internal error
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:533)
    ... 16 more````
`````

Comment: Notice that you are using very old versions, I would upgrade o the latest 1.4 image and to spark-bigquery-connector 0.20.